# In Ruby on Rails is it standard to use hashes or classes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am retrieving JSON from a third party API, and want to bind that information to the front end. I thought of creating a class for the information, but I've also noticed that hashes can be used. What is the standard convention in Rails? Should I bind directly to the front end using a hash? Or should I model my own classes and then bind?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer: go with `Hash`.

The long answer: it depends.
What do you need to do with this data? If you know that you'll need to manipulate it, or that you'll end up with a lot of helper functions to extract and present subset of the data, then a dedicated class might serve you better.

Still, there is a spectrum of possibilities.
A minimum approach would be to not use a "class with public properties", but instead a thin class with composition. Define a ruby class that holds the deserialized JSON in a `Hash`, then define instance methods that act on the `Hash`.
At the other end of the spectrum we have classes with attributes that hold all the deserialized data. These work well if the deserialized data will act as an entity in your application as opposed to plain stuff to be temporarily held in memory and presented. See also [value objects](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ValueObject).

Comment: Thanks for the reply @tompave I will certainly take this advice into consideration